# Git: Stop Auto-merge when merging copied directory

Tags: git

I have a master branch, and a "newfeature" branch.

In my newfeature branch, I copied directory A, calling the new folder Directory B.

I then deleted directory A in "newfeature", just to make sure I wouldn't accidentally change anything there, as my new feature was to be in Directory B.

I did some work in "newfeature", and committed it.

Then, from master, I tried to merge in "newfeature" (git merge newfeature).

However, git merges my changed files in Directory B (from "newfeature") with my files in Directory A (in "master"), and I'm just left with a Directory B. The message is like this:

Auto-merging B/somefile.php

How can I retain both Directory A, and Directory B, when merging?

Comment: Do you still have folder A files in newfeature?

Comment: So on newfeature both directory A and B exist?

Comment: Sorry, very good question. I just edited my question and added this:  "I then deleted directory A in "newfeature", just to make sure I wouldn't accidentally change anything there, as my new feature was to be in Directory B."

Comment: What do you expect your master branch to look like after the merge? Like you described it, I would expect it to only contain directory `B` (since `A` was deleted in the branch, so it will also get deleted when merging)

Comment: You're Right. This would require a "hack", and that's not good. I just reverted my directory A back to a commit that occurred before the merge (as some files within were edited), then committed that in newfeature, and was able to merge into master.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in preserving history for the directory you copied ? If not, see below:
When you copied directory A as directory B in new branch, you shouldn't run "git cp". Just do a "cp".
check the following sequence of commands I ran to achieve this.

```
ls -al
  cp -rf data-trial test
  mkdir test; sudo cp -rf data-trial/* test/
  cd test
  cp -rf data-trial/.git .
  cp -rf data-trial/.git .
  git branch
  git checkout -b test2
  cp -rf tmp tmp2
  git add tmp2
  git commit 
  git log
  git branch
  git checkout feature/aws
  cd tmp
  ls -al
  touch foo
  vim foo
  git status
  git add foo
  git commit
  git log
  git branch
  git checkout test2
  sudo git checkout test2
  git merge feature/aws
  sudo git merge feature/aws
  ls -al
  pwd
  cd ..
  ls -al
  ls -al tmp
  ls -al tmp2
```

Comment: what is `git cp`?? And why all the sudos?

Comment: `git cp` does not exist. Also, git makes no difference whether you copied the files by hand or by using git commands. Rename detection happens later during merge, not during the initial commit.